# How to catch link or button click?

Tags: c#, asp.net, javascript

How do I catch all links and button pressed?
Without having to add my JavaScript method to every link and button?

Anytime my browser wanrs to redirect to page1.aspx
stop it from redirecting and have mt browser click a link found on the page to page2.aspx 
instead!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
            $(document).ready(function(){
              $("a,:button").click(function(){
               alert("Link or button clicked!");
              });
            });
```

Comment: +0 for not mentioning that it's JQuery

Answer (score 0):

I think "Babiker's" solution is better than "Bears will eat you" because it calls the event handler only when link of button is clicked whereas in the other case, it calls for all the click events on the page and checks if the element clicked was a link or button.

Babiker's solution is more optimized.

Note, this wont work for any elements added in future.

You might wanna try this.

```
$("a, button").live("click", function(){ ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"<script type=""text/javascript"" src=""http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js""></script>  

<script type=""text/javascript""> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('body').click(function() {
           // do something here
        //alert(""Link or button clicked!"");
        });
    });
</script>"
```